# Should I remove Thank You when editing a question?

Tags: discussion

When editing a question: should we remove statements such as: *thanks*, *thank you in advance* ...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I generally remove most commentary parts of a question.  If there's a paragraph of backstory that doesn't actually contribute to the question I would remove it.  I think the same applies to "Thanks" or "Any help is appreciated".

If it's the only thing I would remove, then I generally just leave it.  But if I'm editing a post anyway then I will.  The same goes for "UPDATE" or "EDIT".

Comment: That is exactly what a moderator told me recently. But is not *thanks* a part of [be nice](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy? Personally I make more efforts to answer to people who write things such as *Thank you in advance*

Comment: It could be, but I view the "Be Nice" policy as how you should conduct yourself.  The overall tone of a question, answer or comment.  The "Thanks" just doesn't add anything to the question.